# How to properly call parentheses list elements in Prolog

Tags: arrays, list, prolog

Regards, i have the next knowledge base:

```
linea(1,[observatorio,tacubaya,juanacatlan,chapultepec,sevilla,cuahtemoc,
     balderas,salto_del_agua,isabel_la_catolica,pino_suarez,merced,
     candelaria,san_lazaro,moctezuma,balbuena,bulevard_puerto_aereo,
     gomez_farias,zaragoza,pantitlan]
linea(2,[cuatro_caminos,panteones,tacuba,cuitlahuac,popotla,colegio_militar,
     normal,san_cosme,revolucion,hidalgo,bellas_artes,allende,zocalo,
     pino_suarez,san_antonio_abad,chabacano,viaducto,xola,villa_de_cortes,
     nativitas,portales,ermita,general_anaya,tasquena]).
linea(3,[indios_verdes,deportivo_18_de_marzo,potrero,la_raza,tlatelolco,
     guerrero,hidalgo,juarez,balderas,nignos_heroes,hospital_general,
     centro_medico,etiopia,eugenia,division_del_norte,zapata,coyoacan,
     viveros,miguel_angel_de_quevedo,copilco,universidad]).
linea(4,[martin_carrera,talisman,bondojito,consulado,canal_del_norte,
     morelos,candelaria,fray_servando,jamaica,santa_anita]).
linea(5,[politecnico,instituto_del_petroleo,autobuses_norte,la_raza,misterios,
     valle_gomez,consulado,eduardo_molina,aragon,oceania,terminal_aerea,
     hangares,pantitlan]).
linea(6,[el_rosario,tezozomoc,azcapotzalco,ferreria,norte_45,vallejo,
     instituto_del_petroleo,lindavista,deportivo_18_de_marzo,basilica,
     martin_carrera]).
linea(7,[el_rosario,aquiles_serdan,camarones,refineria,tacuba,
     rio_san_joaquin,polanco,auditorio,constituyentes,tacubaya,
     san_pedro_de_los_pinos,san_antonio,mixcoac,barranca_del_muerto]).
linea(8,[garibaldi,bellas_artes,san_juan_de_letran,salto_del_agua,
     doctores,obrera,chabacano,la_viga,santa_anita,coyuya,iztacalco,
     apatlaco,aculco,escuadron_201,atlalilco,iztapalapa,
     cerro_de_la_estrella,uami,constitucion_de_1917]).
linea(9,[tacubaya,patriotismo,chilpancingo,centro_medico,lazaro_cardenas,
     chabacano,jamaica,mixihuca,velodromo,ciudad_deportiva,puebla,
     pantitlan]).
linea(a,[pantitlan, agricola_oriental,canal_de_san_juan,tepalcates,guelatao,
     pegnon_viejo,acatitla,santa_marta,los_reyes,la_paz]).
linea(b,[ciudad_azteca,plaza_aragon,olimpica,ecatepec,muzquiz,
     rio_de_los_remedios,impulsora,nezahualcoyotl,villa_de_aragon,
     bosque_de_aragon,deportivo_oceania,oceania,romero_rubio,
     r_flores_magon,san_lazaro,morelos,tepito,lagunilla,garibaldi,
     guerrero,buenavista]).
linea(12,[mixcoac,insurgentes_sur,hospital_20_de_noviembre,zapata,
      parque_de_los_venados,eje_central,ermita,mexicaltzingo,
      atlalico,culhuacan,san_andres_tomatlan,lomas_estrella,calle_11,
      periferico_oriente,tezonco,olivos,nopalera,zapotitlan,
      tlaltenco,tlahuac]).
```

... and the next functions:

```
member(X,[X|Xs]).
member(X,[Y|Xs]):-member(X,Xs).

append([],X,X).
append([X|Xs],Ys,[X|Zs]):-append(Xs,Ys,Zs).
```

What i'm trying to do is to check, for example, if the element 'mixcoac' belongs to the linea(12)'s array which is something like the 2nd element, but i don't know how to work this kind of lists in the Prolog syntax.

I tried to execute `member(mixcoac, 12).` but that doesn't work.

Comment: Those are standard predicate names, and they already exist: [member](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=member/2) and [append](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=append/3). 12 is not a list.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
?- linea(12, L), member(mixcoac, L).
L = [mixcoac, insurgentes_sur, hospital_20_de_noviembre, zapata, parque_de_los_venados, eje_central, ermita, mexicaltzingo, atlalico|...] ;
false.
```

This query succeeds once and fails on backtracking. This means that the element `mixcoac` is seen once in the list of `linea(12, L)`.

---

The listing I show above is specific to SWI-Prolog, and the fact we are using the toplevel (the interactive shell), and how it is configured by default. This means that other Prologs will look different, and running the code differently will look different. For example, you can use "anonymous variables", starting with underscore, for the list; and you can configure SWI-Prolog's toplevel to not show the bindings for anonymous variables. With *nothing else to show*, you will get your "true":

```
?- set_prolog_flag(toplevel_print_anon, false).
true.

?- linea(12, _L), member(mixcoac, _L).
true .
```

I also typed <kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of <kbd>;</kbd> after the "true". This way I didn't ask for more solutions and I didn't get a "false" ie "there are no more solutions".

All of this under the line is completely irrelevant to your original question.

Also, from your question:

> but i don't know how to work this kind of lists in the Prolog syntax.

This has nothing to do with syntax it feels. Some generic tutorial should have taught you all you need to know.

Comment: Thanks for your response; but what should have to be coded to have an answer of true? I mean, the 'mixcoac' value is in there on linea(12).

Comment: The first answer *is* true, i.e. succeeds. The second answer means that `member` continued searching the list, and didn't find a 2nd match (failed, hence `false`). You probably want to replace `member` with [memberchk](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=memberchk/2), to prevent continuing to search after 1 match.

Comment: @JoelGiroud This is an impicit "true", the solution you get. Depending on your Prolog it might say "yes" (gnu-prolog), "true" (maybe some other prolog) or omit the "yes/true" because it is obvious (SWI-Prolog). I will also show how to trick SWI-Prolog to print "true" in this particular case, see my edited answer!

Comment: @brebs There are good reasons to use memberchk/2 but I wouldn't _recommend_ it if I don't fully understand the use case.